# Call a JavaScript function in the child window

Tags: javascript

I have the exact same requirement as in [Javascript,calling child window function from opener doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117887/javascript-calling-child-window-function-from-opener-doesnt-work), to call a JavaScript function defined in the child window (when a user clicks a link in the parent window)
But the child window is from a different domain
Is there still some way I can invoke a JavaScript function on the child window?
Otherwise is there a workaround?

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, you cannot interact with a page in a different domain.
Period.

Instead, you can communicate through a server using JSONP.