# How to call a function from another HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, function, window.open

I want to call a function from another HTML web page I create.

If the second Javascript function is this:

```
function g(x){
   alert(x);
}
```

So I tried this in the first page:

```
function f(){
    var x = prompt("enter");
    testwindow = window.open("otherWebPage.html", "_self");
    testwindow.g(x);
}
f();
```

but its not working. Where did I go wrong?

(it's not really my code in the page, i just gave a simple example)

Comment: What does the JavaScript error console say?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript,calling child window function from opener doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117887/javascript-calling-child-window-function-from-opener-doesnt-work)

Comment: bind a load handler to the new window. New page has to load for your function to be there

Comment: Have you tried giving it a timeOut?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are calling `testwindow.g` before the code in `otherWebPage.html` has run. You need to wait for the necessary function to be available.

There are several ways to do this, but here is a simple example for how to do this by waiting for the `load` event.

```
function f(){
    var x = prompt("enter");
    testwindow = window.open("otherWebPage.html", "_self");
    testwindow.addEventListener('load', function(){
        testwindow.g(x);
    });
}
f();
```

Comment: @AmalPrasad There must be something else at play. You might try making an MCVE and posting a new question seeking debugging help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
window.open("otherWebPage.html", "_self");
```

loads "otherWebPage.html" in the current page, which is unloaded.

And an unloaded page can't call functions.