# HTML/JavaScript - link to a page and click on a button once there

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have two pages, Page 1 and Page 2.
Page 2 has several buttons on it that call a JavaScript function, displaying text (I don't think that code is relevant for this, so I'll omit).

What I need is to create links on Page 1 that link to Page 2 and click appropriate buttons.

If a user clicks on LINK1 on Page 1, she should go to Page 2 and trigger a click of a certain button there.

Is something like this possible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: use anchor tags <a href="url"></a>

Comment: Do you know about `< a href="https:// domain.com" >`?

Comment: Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892595/how-to-call-a-function-from-another-html-page

Comment: Kannan, theAlexandrian - I know how to create a link, but not how to click on a button on the page I link to, from the <a> element.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'll have a look.

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117887/javascript-calling-child-window-function-from-opener-doesnt-work

Comment: What should happen, when that button is "clicked" on the second page?

Comment: @Andreas - Page2 has blocks of text wrapped in divs, with display:none. I have a couple of buttons that trigger a JavaScript function that displays certain block, changing the style to display:block.

Now I want to link from Page1 to Page2 and display a certain block on Page2. I thought the easiest would be to link to Page2 and trigger a click to the appropriate button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like (not tested):

Page 1:

```
<a href="page2.html?action=triggerClick"/>Link</a>
```

Page 2:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var url = new URL(window.location.href);
  var action = url.searchParams.get('action');
  if (action == 'triggerClick') {
    document.getElementById('buttonId').click();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

On page two, you can add this to the start of the script:

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(#div).show();

});
```

Or in vanilla:

```
window.onload = function() {

 document.getElementById("div").display = "block";

};
```

The thing is, if I understand correctly what you asked, you don't need to trigger the button, you can just show the div. This might bring some problems, if you want the button to now hide the div. But you can add a simple function that just changes from hide to show, and from show to hide.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But this would only show specific div every time the page loads, right? I have several divs on the page, and I want the link to open the page and show only the div that I want, so I need to somehow tell it which div to show from the first page, from where I'm linking.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. On the first page I use links like this:

```
<a href="page2.html?firstButton">First Link<a>
```

The script on the second page:

```
var clickTrigger = window.location.search.substring(1);
window.onload = function() {
     document.getElementById(clickTrigger).click();
    }
```

The buttons on the second page all have IDs that correspond to the clickTriggers I'm using in the links on the first page.

Thanks, everyone!!