# function window.focus() doesn't work on opener object

Tags: javascript

I have a webapp which can use two windows and i want to switch between them by javascript. Here's my attempt:

```
var opposite = window.opener;
    
function showOpposite() {
    if( opposite === null || opposite.closed ) {
        // maybe later a customized targetUrl
        opposite = window.open(window.location.toString(),"_blank");
    } else {
        opposite.blur();
        window.blur();
        opposite.focus();
    }
}
```

by calling `showOpposite()` from the first window, this works fine. But calling it from the second window nothing happens. I've tried also different combinations to not call the `blur()`-functions in the else block with no effect.

Then I added some code inspired by [Javascript,calling child window function from opener doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117887/javascript-calling-child-window-function-from-opener-doesnt-work) but this also doesn't have a better effect, though I ensured `opposite` is assigned by `registerOpener()`:

```
// will then initial be called after window.open in showOpposite()
function registerOnOpened(opened) {
    if(!opened.registerOpener) {
        setTimeout(function(){registerOnOpened(opened);},1000);
    } else {
        opened.registerOpener(opened);
    }
}
    
function registerOpener(o) {
    console.log("registerOpener has been called :-)");
    opposite = o;
}
```

Comment: about:config says 'browser.tabs.remote.useCrossOriginOpenerPolicy=false'. Changing it to true doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Is it simply that you have two windows `A` and `B`. `A` opens `B`, so `A` is `B`'s opener, but `A` won't have an opener, so you're trying to call `focus` on `null`?

Comment: [`focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus) "may fail due to user settings and the window isn't guaranteed to be frontmost before this method returns." So it could just be that it's failing silently

Comment: @MattEllen You're right with `A` and `B`. But, when `A` first comes with no `opener`, `opposite` will be `null` and `showOpposite()` assign the `window.open`-Result to `opposite`-var. So next time it can just focus on that window. When `A` creates `B`, `B` will get `A` as its `opener` and also `opposite`-var.

Comment: But then you'll have 3 windows, won't you?

Comment: @MattEllen No. Just try it yourself. The only thing happens at me, that by calling `showOpposite()` from `B` doesn't grab the focus of `A` though I've ensured by console-logging, that `focus` is called on `A`.

Comment: I think I understand. I can call `focus()` on the opened window, but I can't call it on the opener. Very weird. Probably a security feature to prevent hiding popups